# I am getting an error installing Magento 2 using the composer in ubuntu

Tags: magento2.3

when I install Magento 2 setup using composer in ubuntu I am getting this issue it's permission issue and me also giving 755 permission to my htdocs.

[image]

Comment: create a directory magento, give that directory 775 permission than try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this with **sudo**:

1)
**sudo** composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition

2) Second be sure you have access keys from magento.

Comment: Thank you Ruel my Magento 2 installation starts now.

Comment: sudo with the composer is not a good practice